# Simulating Virtual Users for Smartphone App based Service

Tags: iphone, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, simulation, traffic

Apologies if something similar has been asked in the future but my search didn't return, what I would consider, directly related.

I am trying to implement a service with its backend in AWS EC2/S3 and front-end in iPhone and the service is more or less like a todo-list. This is not a novel idea but will help me in a class I teach about IT infrastructure.

Unfortunately I have access to only my own iPhone and I cannot demonstrate scalability over AWS, etc.

*Is there a way/software tool/framework to simulate virtual users for this app that can send requests to the AWS servers pretending to be from different accounts/apps? 
The simulator should send requests just like my actual iphone app would send if I were to add an item to the list or delete or edit.*

I understand stress testing is a well established topic but here I want to just simulate multiple users and demonstrate scalability instead of trying to push the Web service to its limits. Neither am I sure if this completely overlaps with traffic simulation.

Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to do it using Apache JMeter. That depends on what you have going on on the backend. But it supports the following server types:

```
Web - HTTP, HTTPS
SOAP
Database via JDBC
LDAP
JMS
Mail - SMTP(S), POP3(S) and IMAP(S)
Native commands or shell scripts
```

You should be able to wire something together with that.

```
 http://jmeter.apache.org/
 http://www.opensourcetesting.org/performance.php
```

I've used it at various points to simulate VERY heavy loads for my services running in AWS/EC2.

Answer (score 0):

[Apache Benchmark](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html) is a very convenient tool for doing HTTP load testing -- you can have it make concurrent requests to simulate multiple users. It's main advantage over other tools is that it's simple and easy to get started with. If your backend listens on HTTP, it might be worth trying `ab` before investing any time in something more complex.